# how do I get the number of markers currently on google maps v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using `Google maps v3` and I am wondering if it is possible to call a function that returns the number of markers currently on that map regardless of `zoom`.

Comment: You are not the owner of the map/code? Otherwise, keep a list of all the references before you put them in there.

Comment: Yes, that is a solution. If there isn't a function that returns a number, I guess I can do that... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API doesn't have a function of the form `getAllMarkers()`. So, handle them from the start with:

```
var myMarkers = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(...);
    myMarkers.push(marker);
}

// process, delete myMarkers
```

Comment: if this is in fact... I guess it's the only answer :( okay

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAllMarkers () 
{
    alert("size: " + myMarkersArray.length());
}
```